# Rails how to view a txt file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How is it possiable to open an view a txt file with rails?

Example I have test.txt:

```
Test test test test
```

Then I have my test.html.erb:

```
Here I want to view test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either [render an arbitrary file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-arbitrary-file) or use `send_file`: [3.1](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file) or [< 3.1](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is:

```
Here is the test.txt file: <%= File.read("test.txt") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the test.txt file:

```
<%= File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'your_folder','your_folder','test.txt'))%>
```

Comment: `Rails.root` is a `Pathname`, so you can `Rails.root.join(...)`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (when the file is not small and loading it is connected with a delay), I prefer to load the page content and then to use `jQuery` ajax request to load the file content.

For example, let's say I have a model with file path attribute. In the `view` layout I am doing something like this:

```
<pre data-source=" <%= (@file.path) %>"></pre>
```

Then in the corresponding `js` file I am loading the context like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax(
    url: $("pre").data("source")
    context: document.body
  ).done (response) ->
    $("pre").html response
    return
  return
```

Of course you can check the [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation for more options. For example, you can render the `pre` tag with `loading` like this:

```
<pre data-source=" <%= (@file.path) %>"><div class="loading"></pre>
```

or use other `jQuery` animations as well.