# I want to display the content of a text file on a static page in rails 4

Tags: file, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I have a content that is very large and I don't want my html.erb file looks bad as it will be full of text. I know in Java we can do this but I am pretty much new to rails and hence I cannot do it.

Also, is there a command or a way to return the file path.

Answer (score 5):

In your controller, do

```
@data = File.read("path/to/file.txt")
```

and in your view(html.erb),

```
<%= @data %>
```

or 
In your view(html.erb), do

```
<%= File.read("path/to/file.txt") %>
```

Similar Question: [Rails how to view a txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627416/rails-how-to-view-a-txt-file)